# serialized attributes solution in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I upgraded to ruby Rails 3.2 from 3.o
I used this serialized attributes solution:

> https://github.com/emmapersky/serialized_attributes

with code that looks like this:

```
serialized_attr :body_data, :entry_data, :class_name => :hash,
              :accessors => BODY_ATTRS
```

saving the model still works for me. but reading the model back isn't working. the attribute is coming back nil

is there a different solution for rails 3.2? 
thanks

---- edit:
OK i found something. in new entries since the upgrade the hash in the DB looks like this:

```
---
- !ruby/object:Hash
time: "22"
```

and before the upgrade it looked like this:

```
---
- time: "22"
```

old entries work. and it is able to "read" them back from the DB
so where does that string of ruby came from? and how can i get rid of it?

Comment: "but reading the model back isn't working", how? what errors are you getting?

Comment: are you saving and retrieving records from the same version? Or saving in 3.0 and reading in 3.2?

Comment: im saving in 3.2 and "reading" in 3.2.
what i mean is that when i get the record. and try to reference the attribute its nil

Comment: I'm having the same problem sometimes with https://github.com/gregmoreno/fancy_serializer - seems to usually work but sometimes not